# How to make large images load faster on my webpage?

Tags: html, performance

I see websites like

1. http://www.kennedyandoswald.com/#!/premiere-screen
2. http://minimums.com/
3. http://www.world-of-swiss.com/en

and many more which have huge images on them covering virtually the whole page, and they load very quick. But when I tried adding a large image to my page (around 1.4mb) it took 4 seconds to load, which in terms of the internet, is an extremely long time.

What are methods of being able to speed up the load times without just using a smaller photo, because these websites don't use small photos, virtually the whole screen is images besides the nav bar?

I have tried saving the image at a lower quality (managed to get it down to around 160kb but it looked like minecraft so it was a no go).

I use goDaddy hosting which is a fairly large company so I assume that their servers can handle a fair amount of trafffic, perhaps I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

images always loadable. if your code in PHP so there is one solution.
when you upload image that time convert it in blob and store in database.
it's faster load large image in your webpage.

you can also use base64 PHP function for blob image.